# splitting wikipedia dump file into several xml files

Tags: php, xml, wikipedia

i am currently doing some experiment which make use of wikipedia articles. 
a wikipedia dump file is about 30gb. Are there tools available (preferably php) or some script which can split this one whole big file into chunks (one xml file per article)?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an article: [Building a (fast) Wikipedia offline reader](http://users.softlab.ece.ntua.gr/~ttsiod/buildWikipediaOffline.html) which describes something similar

It may not rely on PHP as much as you like, but it discusses splitting the dump file into manageable portions.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use the excellent [XMLReader](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xmlreader.php), which allows you to read an xml file node by node, instead of loading the entire file into memory first.

You can still browse the node with DOM or SimpleXML after that!